# QSqlQuery using hundreds of MB of memory

Tags: c++, sql, database, performance, qt

I'm using a `QSqlQuery` object to do a linear walk of a 10million row SQL table with a very complex 6 column primary key in sorted order. Because of the key(which I CAN NOT change), breaking upmy query `SELECT * FROM table1` with `<` or `>` with `LIMIT` causes a huge number of issues with the algorithm I'm using.

My problem arising is as follows, for whatever reason `QSqlQuery` seems to be caching the entire result set in memory until it hits a bad alloc and kills the application. So I may read some couple hundred rows, `seek()` over a couple hundred thousand, and by this point `QSqlQuery` is using 300mb of memory and my application dies. I read the docs and it seems the only thing that can be done is to use `setForwardOnly()`, however I often have a need for `previous()`(which is why breaking up the query with LIMIT is a PITA)

Is there no way to cap the cache for `QSqlQuery`?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you store `previous` yourself? There's a `QContiguousCache` which seems ideal for this.

Comment: Cause the algorithm could potentially call previous() as many times as there are items in the table.

Comment: To elaborate: these rows are being drawn into a very large graph/diagram depicting events in the table and the application has to draw this.

Comment: Well, that's where the `LIMIT` clause comes back then. You cache N results in `QContiguousCache`, and use `LIMIT X*N, (X+1)*N`. But if you're essentially doing a random walk through the result set, you should go back to the drawing board.

Comment: The randomness comes from the user, I can't make them scroll in one direction in order.

LIMIT is useless because I'm using a sqlite database, LIMIT doesn't speed up queries.... doing LIMIT 9000000, 9000001 takes something like 9 seconds. edit: sorry, it takes 39 seconds

Comment: @JohnLotacs: back to the drawing board, then. QSqlQuery has no reasonable alternative but to store the first 9 million rows in that example.

Comment: I can't make a user not random.

Comment: Also, why SHOULD it have to store all rows in memory? Wouldn't it make sense for it to map a rowid to an index instead of attempting to load an entire 600mb table into memory? sqlite is already caching things as well, why should QSqlQuery?